# Images styles are not created in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a website in drupal 7.53. When I try to upload an image in my article, it shows the image as a cross (image not found). For testing pruposes, I've set my folders to 777:

- sites/default
- sites/default/files
- sites/default/files/tmp

But no luck.

**Edit:**
I've changed the "clean url" option to no clean urls and now it starts working. So I've replaces the .htaccess file to the default drupal file, but still no luck when I turn on "clean url".

Comment: check the image path from the developer tools or use firebug and the check manually image at the same location image is exist or not. and then open image url in new tab check  what error message you get

Comment: can you provide error logs?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience most common reasons that can cause image style image creation failure are:

- GD library not installed or not working properly
- Wrong file permissions (php can't upload/write file)
- Domain access module (it's "Locale" sub-moduel) - there's a bug in that module which messes up the image paths.
- .htaccess file (some wrong options)

What I would do is try the fresh installation on same environment and if it's working well there or not and then I would switch off temporary module by module to see what is causing this issue. Also try switching to default Drupal's theme to see will it happen with it too.